# What does Kubernetes AccessMode represent?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes

No matter how many times I read the documentation I just don't get it, so apologies for the really basic question.

I read that once a PersistentVolume is claimed, no other Pod can claim it - claims are exclusive.

However PV accessmodes have options including *Many. These two seem to contradict each other.

What is the Once or the Many in the access mode types?  Does it refer to multiple replicas of the same pod across different nodes. Or does it mean after one claim has been released, can another pod then claim it? Or does it refer to the underlying storage which could be referenced by a different PV? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I read that once a PersistentVolume is claimed, no other Pod can claim it - claims are exclusive.

This is a misunderstanding. It should be: once a `PersistentVolume` is claimed, no other `PersistentVolumeClaim` can claim it - claims are exclusive.

But multiple Pods can use the same `PersistentVolumeClaim` - it is not so common - but this is typically what happens when you "upgrade" your application, both new and old version of your app might use the PVC for a short time.

### Access Modes

[Access Modes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) on Persistent Volumes is related to how the volumes can be mounted on **nodes**. This is related to how your storage system works, so you must check what *access modes* is available for your *storage system*.

The modes ending with -Once can only be mounted on a single node at a time - this is unrelated to Pods. The mode ending with -Many can be mounted on multiple nodes at the same time, typical for NFS-style storage systems.

Comment: Great explanation thanks, and clears up my (obvious) confusion.  If I may ask for one more real-world clarification. In the situation where you are scaling horizontally and not sure on what node your replica will be scheduled, I guess you need to be using storage that supports  -Many?

Comment: It is not easy to horizontally scale an app that use PVC, typically you use `StatefulSet` that has an unique PVC for each replica. Otherwise you may need `ReadWriteMany` that typically is NFS-backed.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for taking the time to help me out.